# Horizontal Accordion for multilevel UL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been looking at the plethora of horizontal accordion scripts on google.

for example:
http://www.leigeber.com/2008/05/horizontal-javascript-accordion-menu/
http://www.nyokiglitter.com/tutorials/horizontal.html
http://designreviver.com/tutorials/jquery-examples-horizontal-accordion/

All the scripts seem to be made for displaying content in a static width div/element.

I'm trying to make a fairly straight forward navigation menu.
When an element in the top-level UL is clicked, the bottom level UL "slides" out, if you click again if closes.  I guess I'd have to calculate the widths "dynamically"... not sure how to proceed.

An example would be this:

```
    <style type="text/css">
<!--
ul.menu, ul.menu ul{ 
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    }
ul.menu li, ul.menu ul li {
    display: inline;
}

a, a:link, a:hover, a:visited, a:active {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
-->
</style>


<ul class="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Top-level 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Top-level 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Bottom Level A1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bottom Level A2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bottom Level A3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bottom Level A4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Top-level 3</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Bottom Level B1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bottom Level B2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Top-level 4</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why are you concerned with the widths? You could use white-space: nowrap; or change your " " to " " if you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this like so:

```
var $current = null;

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("ul li ul").hide(); // hide submenus by default on load

   $("ul li a").click(function(){
      var $sub = $(this).find("ul"); // could also use $(this).next();

      if ($sub.css("display") == "none")
      {
         if ($current != null)
            $current.slideUp(); // if you want to only show one sub at a time
         $sub.slideDown();
         $current = $sub;
      }
      else
      {
         $sub.slideUp();
         $current = null;
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: instead of slideUp/slideDown you'll want to use animate()

Answer (score 1):

I was using `$(this).outerWidth()` to calculate how far `$sub` should move over, but it doesn’t seem to work with this example. Not too helpful, but it might point you in the right direction. (also, you’ve hopefully solved this issue by now)

Answer (score 0):

"instead of slideUp/slideDown you'll want to use animate()"

I guess that is where I was getting hung up... I'm not sure how to calculate the widths of the bottom-level UL on the fly (if this is even necessary)

Answer (score 0):

For Instance:

```
   var $current = null;
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("ul li ul").hide(); // hide submenus by default on load

   $("ul li a").click(function(){
      var $sub = $(this).next(); 
      if ($sub.css("display") == "none")
      {
         if ($current != null)
            $current.animate({ width: 'hide' }); // if you want to only show one sub at a time
         $sub.animate({ width: 'show' }); 
         $current = $sub;
      }
      else
      {
         $sub.animate({ width: 'hide' });
         $current = null;
      }
   });
});
```

I would think this would work, but it just seems like a variant of slide up, it doesn't really work as a "slideRight" "slideLeft" function.  Maybe its the css?